# After creating form in sitefinity facing issue : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity, sitefinity-feather

In sitefinity 9.1, We created a mvc only form using form control then we drag and drop this form in page. After placing form inside the Page we facing issues of Jquery from    ScriptResource.axd & it's related showing message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined

Doesn't know why facing this issue from sitefinity.Also ask same on sitefinity forum for support : [http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/after-creating-form-in-sitefinity-facing-issue-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-'queryselectorall'-of-undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXQfc.png)

Comment: in the dev toolbar - can you click on that link contact-us:788 and show us the code that is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Is your form being placed on a page whose template is an ASP.NET Master Page? [I blogged about this particular error before](https://blog.falafel.com/beginformsitefinity-js-error/), and for me the cause has always been that the `<form>` tag in the master page has an id of something *different from* `aspnetForm`. If you have a master page whose `<form>` ID is something other than `aspnetForm` then Sitefinity's forms won't work. This is because Sitefinity's form-submission JavaScript is hardcoded to look for that particular form ID.